# Calculating the Excess 3 code

Tags: conversion

What should be excess 3 equivalent for (1234)H ?

I know that for decimal no we can find out the excess 3 code by adding 3 to each digit of the decimal number but not aware that how to fetch it for Hexa decimal.

Thanks,

Comment: While I cannot find a rule based reason to close the question, I feel remis if I do not at least scold for the fact googling Excess-3 would have given you the wikipedia page showing a full XS3 table from which one should at the least be able to form a more informed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Excess-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excess-3) code can only code decimal numbers.

To convert 0x1234 to Excess-3 it is necessary to convert it to decimal (base 10) and encode each digit in Excess-3. This is left as an exercise for the OP.